# Element with absolute positioning fails to be responsive

Tags: html, css

I know there have been several questions on the subject but none of them quite answers my problem... I have 13 SVGs piled one over the other (I am using a JS script to make one appear and the other disappear, thus creating an "animation" effect where something moves from one position to the other) and I positioned them as absolute to have them piled. The problem is: I work on a 17" screen and when I look with screenfly what my page looks like on bigger screens (24"), my elements are not well positioned anymore.

I have already tried positioning it with all the units I knew of (px, %, vw/vh, em, rem) but none of this works for my case...

Here is a schematic HTML code:

```html
<svg id="step1">Lots of stuff</svg>
<svg id="step2">Same here</svg>
.
.
.
<svg id="step13">Some more stuff</svg>
```

And here are the CSS rules I use:

```css
#step1, #step2, #step3, #step4, #step5, #step6, #step7, #step8, #step9, #step10, #step11, #step12, #step13 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 1vh;
  left: 8.5vw;
  margin: 0 auto;
  visibility: hidden; /*They are hidden by default and I use JS to make them visible alternatively.*/
  height: 150px;
}
```

Here is the [webpage](https://huitiemecouleur.com/accueil-2/) for the animation, the one I am talking about is the "Tetris" animation for mobile phones so maybe you'll have to resize your browser to see it well...

If anyone has an idea about how to make it responsively positioned, I'd be really thankful.

Benjamin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use **media query** to resolve responsive issue. Try this i hope it'll help you out. Thanks

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 768px) {
  .step {
    position: static;
    display: block;
  }
}
```

```css
.step {
  position: absolute;
  top: 1vh;
  left: 8.5vw;
  margin: 0 auto;
  visibility: hidden; /*They are hidden by default and I use JS to make them visible alternatively.*/
  height: 150px;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 768px) {
  .step {
 position: static;
 display: block;
  }
}
```

```html
<svg class="step" id="step1">Lots of stuff</svg>
<svg class="step" id="step2">Same here</svg>
.
.
.
<svg class="step" id="step13">Some more stuff</svg>
```

Comment: I will probably resolve to that but I was trying to avoid it because if I do it like that I will have to specify a lot of widths since my code isn't even responsive from one computer screen to another. But thank you for your help :)

I will try it now and will put the questioned as solved if it works!

Comment: Thank you @BenjaminLoubet for your feedback.

Comment: Sorry for the late answer, I couldn't do it at the time I thought I would but now my element is responsive, thanks to you @HassanSiddiqui!

Answer (score 2):

Have you looked at `flexbox` with a columnar direction? The items will stay vertically centered no matter the screen height. Also, I removed the `id`s, since they are no longer necessary.

```js
const steps = document.querySelectorAll('.step');
let delay = .25;
steps.forEach(step => {
  step.style.animationDelay = `${delay}s`;
  delay += .25;
});
```

```css
body {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  min-height: 100vh;
  margin: 0;
}

.step {
  visibility: hidden;
  opacity: 0;
  border: 1px solid;
  animation-name: makeVisible;
  animation-duration: 1s;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
  padding: 1em;
}

@keyframes makeVisible {
  to {
    opacity: 1;
    visibility: visible;
    border-color: transparent;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="step">One</div>
<div class="step">Two</div>
<div class="step">Three</div>
<div class="step">Four</div>
<div class="step">Five</div>
```

[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/q1z03ano/)

Comment: Good suggestion but in future if step length increase we have to write **animation-delay CSS** for each step.

Comment: @HassanSiddiqui I adjusted my answer to grow dynamically with `n` elements via `JavaScript`.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help, however, it doesn't seem to work for vertical positioning... I will edit the question to provide the web page so that anyone can look